# Работа с radiobutton?

Tags: delphi

Хочу сделать маленькую программу с ответами "Да" и "Нет" через `radiobutton`.

Например, на форме `1 label`, `2 radiobutton` (сейчас), `1 button` (далее).

В label пишу `"У тебя иномарка"?` Ответы - `Да и Нет`. При клике на `Да`, показываем следующий вопрос: `"Дорогая"?` и также ответы `"Да и Нет"`, соответственно, если нажали на `"Нет"`, то появляется другой вопрос и т.д.

Не хочется создавать кучу radiobuttons, но и надо в конце получить результат в зависимости от ответов.

Как реализовать такое?

```
Изначально
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Title.Caption := 'У тебя иномарка?';
end;

procedure TForm1.NextClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if(Yes.Checked) then
    Title.Caption := 'Honda?';
  if(No.Checked) then
    Title.Caption := 'Москвич?';
end;
```

Ну и в зависимости от этих вариантов должны идти опять radiobutton и задаваться другие вопросы

Comment: покажите сами как реализовали, код. А то за вас не сможем сделать

Comment: Изначально
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
Title.Caption:='У тебя иномарка?';
end;
procedure TForm1.NextClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
 if (Yes.Checked)then
    Title.Caption:='Honda?';
  if (No.Checked) then
    Title.Caption:='Москвич?';
end;
Ну и в зависимости от этих вариантов должны идти опять radiobutton и задаваться другие вопросы

Comment: добавьте код  в вопрос. так есть ссылка на "ПРАВИТЬ" и можете изменить/дополнить вопрос

Comment: добавил в первый пост.

Answer (score 1):

Вешаешь на событие нажатия кнопок Да или Нет следующий код:

```
label.caption := questions(index); 
index := index + 1;
```

В questions - нужно разместить список вопросов. Не забываем инициализировать index...

Comment: Извините, но немного не понял.

Comment: При нажатии на Да или Нет обновляется label новым вопросом...

Answer (score 0):

Нужно отделять интерфейс от логики.

**Логика.** Ответам типа "Да" соответствуют свои вопросы, соответственно "Нет" - свои. То есть логика вашей задачи это связанная структура (в широком смысле) вопросов-ответов в виде дерева, которую нужно программно реализовать  отдельно от всего остального (например графического интерфейса, баз данных, сети, серилизации и тому подобное)

**Графический интерфейс.** А в интерфейсной части все остается неизменным, то есть для любого вопроса (в соответствии с вашим описанием) это `1 label, 2 кнопки "Да" и "Нет" и кнопка "Далее"`, которые обновляются и инициализируются из текущего вопроса.